Python script returning 'TypeError' after being converted to Pyinstaller exe
I have a Python script that executes a SQL query using the pyhive and presto libraries. The script retrieves the query output and converts it into a Pandas DataFrame. Then, I perform some transformations on the DataFrame and use it to generate a PDF file.
The script runs smoothly when executed through PyCharm, which I use for development and testing. However, when I use PyInstaller to create an executable (using either --onefile or --onedir), I encounter the following error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1968, in __call__
  File "gerador_extrato.py", line 1880, in selected
  File "gerador_extrato.py", line 692, in query_buyer
  File "pandas\core\frame.py", line 10374, in apply
  File "pandas\core\apply.py", line 916, in apply
  File "pandas\core\apply.py", line 1063, in apply_standard
  File "pandas\core\apply.py", line 1081, in apply_series_generator
  File "gerador_extrato.py", line 680, in pix_replace
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

The error occurs in the following function:
        def pix_replace(row):
            value = row['fund_transaction_type']
            orides_nome = row['orides_nome']
            orides_taxid_masked = row['orides_taxid_masked']
            transaction_type = row['TRANSACTION_TYPE']

            if value not in [17, 18, 34, 57]:
                return transaction_type
            if value == 17:
                return 'PIX ENVIADO PARA \n ' + orides_nome.upper() + ' - ' + orides_taxid_masked
            if value == 18:
                return 'PIX RECEBIDO DE \n ' + orides_nome.upper() + ' - ' + orides_taxid_masked
            if value == 34:
                return 'PIX RECEBIDO DE \n ' + orides_nome.upper() + ' - ' + orides_taxid_masked
            if value == 57:
                return 'PIX RETORNADO'

        df['Tipo de Transação'] = df.apply(pix_replace, axis=1)

I'm trying to apply this function to transform info of the 'Tipo de Transação' column.
I suspect that the error is related to concatenating a None value with a string. The script runs successfully in my development environment, so I'm unsure why it fails after being transformed into an executable.
I have done the testing using the same inputs on Pycharm and the Executable, but it seems that my executable does not generate the same data and I don't know why.
The values of the column 'orides_taxid_masked', which are considered on this function are:
On Pycharm:
    7              None
    8    ***.273.748-**
    9              None
    Name: orides_taxid_masked, dtype: object

On Executable:
    7    None
    8    None
    9    None
    Name: orides_taxid_masked, dtype: object

I run pyinstaller through a virtual environment, to only use specific libraries to optimize my executable.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue when running the script as an executable.

Please post the full traceback of the error.

Add print(orides_taxid_masked) to see the value of this variable that you're concatenating.

The problem is probably in the code that creates row and calls this function.

If the row is coming from a database query, this would happen if there's a NULL value in the orides_taxid_masked column. You may need to check for this and supply a default value.

E.g. orides_taxid_masked = row['orides_taxid_masked'] or 'noTaxId

This is because you are combining a null and a string. If you try running the following code, you'll get the same error.: '1' + None/ it return TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

However, I don't recommend modifying your code to avoid errors. Don't create unnecessary custom functions, use pandas or numpy functions. I recommend np.select.

@Barmar I edited my question with more info, as said before, both have the same input/query, but it's missing some information when I convert into an executable, on Pycharm the data is there, on the executable it simply does not exist.

The problem is with the source of the data, not this function. You need to figure out where those empty values are coming from.

@Barmar but I'm using the same source on both cases, it's the same code, same SQL query and same inputs. That's what I can't figure out.

So, i figured it out, it seems that the line below was working just fine on Pycharm but when I compiled using Pyinstaller it was not working, impacting my functions, I think this might be due to the Python/Pandas version of my virtual environment.
Pycharm:
df['orides_taxid'] = df['orides_taxid'].str.replace(r'\.', '').str.replace(r'-', '').str.replace(r'/', '')

Pyinstaller:
df['orides_taxid'] = df['orides_taxid'].str.replace(r'.', '').str.replace(r'-', '').str.replace(r'/', '')

